# How to stop CentOS 7 fresh install to stop `clear` from running on exit from ssh session?

Tags: centos, centos7, zsh

I'm finding that upon `exit` from an `ssh` session on a CentOS 7 server, it clears the screen each time.  I suspect that there's a setting in `/etc` for the environment that is doing this.

Any ideas of what's triggering this?

Comment: Check if your `/etc/zlogout` contains `clear`. The `cls` is a DOS/Windows-ism.

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. You're right that `clear` was in `/etc/zlogout` and upon commenting out it's great now.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the shell on the machine that you are connecting to doing this. For instance, if you are connecting from host1 to host2 via ssh and you try both `bash` and `zsh` on host1 but host2 is still using `bash` in both scenarios then most likely there is a `.bash_logout` on host2 that contains a `clear` command in it, remove it and your problem is solved.